# Linux newbie install problems

Tags: system-installation

first post :)

Im having problems installing Ubuntu 14.04, all seems well until restart when it hangs after giving the message "asking all remaining services to close -> OK" or words to that effect, cant remember exactly.

I am trying to set up my laptop (Compac nc8000) to run Ubuntu without ever having connected to the internet as I want to store sensitive info on it long term. So I am not connecting when installing and dont want to connect to update. Perhaps this is making things difficult? Is there a workaround? Or a way to get it to reboot properly and hence finish the install?

Ubuntu starts but nothing looks right. E.g there is no launcher on the left hand side of my desktop and the Driver panel is empty plus lots of other anomalies. I've installed the encrypted disk and also encrypted the /home as its security that I'm concerned with. Nothing else really.

any ideas anyone?

Answer (score 0):

Nothing looked right because i was looking at 14.04 whereas all the videos I had seen were 15.10. that's why it didnt look right. Doh!
It didn't matter that the reboot hung. I shut it off and it (seemed to ) load fine. Although the drivers panel was still empty.

Now trying to upgrade to 15.10 without success as the laptop cannot see the 15.10 dvd for some reason. Any ideas on that?